# Swift [map] return array containing values of specific property

Tags: swift, flatmap

Say i have an array for objects

```
let persons = [Person]

struct Person { 
    let name: String
    let position: Int
}
```

And i wanna return array of strings [String] containing persons' names whose position is equal to 1. 
If there any way to do this using map/flatmap/reduce functions?

Comment: When posting a question like this you should include your own attempt at solving the issue instead of treating stackoverlow like a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid two steps use `compactMap`

```
let positionOneNames = persons.compactMap{$0.position == 1 ? $0.name : nil }
```

Comment: thank you! that's exactly what i need

Comment: Good method! As the code becomes more complex readability reduces.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how:

```
let names = persons
    .filter { $0.position == 1 }
    .map { $0.name }
```